# Defining path variable for a make file

Tags: makefile, compilation

In my assignment instructions, I was told to make a

> Makefile without absolute directory names or derived binary files. Execution of make with no parameters should build the target program "wordpairs". Assume that the environment variable GET_WORD is defined as the pathname of a directory which contains directories "include" and "lib" containing getWord.h and libget.a

My directory for my code contains: [pic](https://i.gyazo.com/3d1c5c5230cce3cc82cc4885a4e219d1.png)

And my Makefile is:

```
#DIR := ${GET_WORD}
DIR := ${CURDIR}
Main : getWord.o crc64.o sTools.o hashingTools.o Main.c libget.a
    gcc -g -o wordpairs Main.c getWord.o crc64.o sTools.o hashingTools.o $(DIR)/lib/libget.a
getWord.o : getWord.c getWord.h
    cc -c $(DIR)/include/getWord.c $(DIR)/include/getWord.h 
#   cc -c getWord.c getWord.h 
crc64.o : crc64.c crc64.h
    cc -c  crc64.c crc64.h
sTools.o : sTools.c sTools.h
    cc -c  sTools.c sTools.h
hashingTools.o : hashingTools.c hashingTools.h
    cc -c  hashingTools.c hashingTools.h
clean :
    rm $(DIR)/include/*.h.gch
```

But when I run make, I get

> make: *** No rule to make target 'getWord.c', needed by 'getWord.o'.  Stop.

The files are in the folders include/lib.

I only understand the basic of make files, so can someone help me out how to achieve what I was assigned to do? What's causing this error?

(updated makefile code)

Comment: Please don't post textual information as images. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So apparently I just need to define GET_WORD variable where the grade can change it to a specific location. The thing is that apparently you cant call variables in the requirement file line (see how I didnt specific anything for getWord.o)

```
GET_WORD = /home/tam#change this!
wordpairs : Main.c crc64.o hashingTools.o sTools.o getWord.o  
    gcc -o wordpairs $^ -I ${GET_WORD}/include ${GET_WORD}/lib/libget.a 
getWord.o :
    cc -c ${GET_WORD}/include/getWord.c ${GET_WORD}/include/getWord.h 
crc64.o : crc64.c crc64.h
    cc -c $^
hashingTools.o : hashingTools.c hashingTools.h
    cc -c $^
sTools.o : sTools.c sTools.h
    cc -c $^
clean :
    rm wordpairs crc64.o hashingTools.o sTools.o *.h.gch
    @echo $(GET_WORD) ${GET_WORD}
```

Answer (score 0):

`getWord.o : getWord.c getWord.h` looks for these files in the current directory.

You should apparently *use* `GET_WORD` to define a couple of additional variables, not redefine it to something else than what's given explicitly in the assignment.

If you figure out how to set `INC` to the `include/` directory, your rule for these files should look something like

```
getWord.o : $(INC)/getWord.c $(INC)/getWord.h
    cc -c $^
```

Notice how a dependency on a file in another directory must include the directory name; and how  `make` won't  actually look at *how* to make a new thing until the dependency resolution forces it to (and even then it doesn't know that a string in the command it runs is equal to one of the dependencies just because the strings are identical, let alone then when they are different, as in your attempt).

Notice also the use of `$^` to say "the things in the dependencies". Generally, you want to avoid repeating information - if you change something, you don't want to change it in many places because it's easy to forget (see also [DRY principle.)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself)

... I don't think the professor wants the `.c` file in the include directory, actually, though; just the `.h` file would be my guess.

As a further aside, to have just `make` without arguments create a particular target, put it as the first target in your `Makefile`.

I hope this is sufficient to help you see how to solve your assigment!

Comment: Hhmmm, that would make sense. But I'm confuse as to why make can't locate files that are in subdirectories when I specified it's absolute path but it's giving me the no rule error in original post. (Sorry I cant post the code since I don't know how to format it in comments)

Comment: You have not specified the full path in the dependency. Nothing in the recipe happens until you have told `make` to make something it knows how to build, and the way to tell it that is by specifying dependencies.

Comment: There's a mechanism called `VPATH` which allows you to avoid specifying explicit directories for everything; but you are clearly not supposed to be using that here.